# Treating a tensorflow Defun as a closure

Tags: tensorflow

I'm having trouble using the Defun decorator in tensorflow. Namely, Defun can't close over any TF ops created outside. Below is a self-contained example showing what I'd like to do. Note that the tensor x belongs to different graphs inside and outside the call to custom_op. The Defun code creates a temporary graph, translates the graph into a function proto, and then merges this into the original graph. The code crashes in the first step, since the tensors that we close over are not in the new temporary graph. Is there a way around this? Being able to close over things would be very helpful.

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    from tensorflow.python.framework import function

    w = tf.Variable(1.0)
    function_factory = lambda x: x*w

    @function.Defun(x=tf.float32)

    def custom_op(x):
        print('graph for x inside custom_op: ', x.graph)
        return function_factory(x)

    x = tf.constant(2.0)

    print('graph for x outside custom_op: ', x.graph)
    y = custom_op(x)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
        sess.run(y)
```

Answer (score 1):

No, the `Defun` decorator does not capture everything. You need to pass in the `w` explicitly, as following in your example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import function

w = tf.Variable(1.0)

@function.Defun(tf.float32, tf.float32)
def custom_op(x, w):
    print('graph for x inside custom_op: ', x.graph)
    return x * w

x = tf.constant(2.0)
print('graph for x outside custom_op: ', x.graph)
y = custom_op(x, tf.identity(w))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    sess.run(y)
```

(we may add more complete support for capturing if the need is high.)